# How to search from the cloud-firestore database?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want users to type their email and password. After Authentication, based on their email I want to check whether they are admin or not and open different activities thereafter. How should I perform the search query? Is it even possible?[image: Database]

Below is the answer which worked for me. For general see Alex answer.

```
mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email,password).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    rootRef.collection("Users").whereEqualTo("Email","ashish@gmail.com").get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                for (DocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                                    if (document.getString("Admin").equals("Yes")) {
                                        Toast.makeText(Login.this, "Logged In!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                        finish();
                                        startActivity(new Intent(Login.this, MainActivity.class));
                                    } else {
                                        Toast.makeText(Login.this, "Logged In!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                        finish();
                                        startActivity(new Intent(Login.this, nonadmin.class));
                                    }
                                }
                            } else {
                                mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                Toast.makeText(Login.this, "Sign In Problem", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        }
                    });

                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To solve this, please use the following code:

```
FirebaseFirestore rootRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
rootRef.collection("Users").whereEqualTo("Email", "ashish@startup.com").get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            for (DocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                if (document.getString("Admin").equals("Yes")) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "User is Admin!");
                }
            }
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "Error getting documents: ", task.getException());
        }
    }
});
```

The output will be: `User is Admin!`.

Don't also forget to set your security rules like this:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You're welcome! Please see my updated answer and tell me if it works.

Comment: Please edit your question by adding the code that you have used to see where the problem is. I test this code and it works perfectly fine.

Comment: I have edited the question. I hope you will understand what I want to do. From what I have observed is that **task.isSuccessful()** is getting false.

Comment: So to understand better, you are getting this message `Sign In Problem`, right? If so, it means that your `mAuth` doesn't work correctly. The code from the if part of the statement is not even triggered. So to solve this, check you `mAuth` object to be correctly instantiated. Did you try my code without as I wrote you, without adding it in the authentication process? Does it work?

Comment: Slight change in the code. But still I am getting `Sign In Problem`. That means `mAuth` is working fine right?

Comment: Yes, that's right. Try to use only my code without adding it in the authentication process? Does it work?

Comment: No. its saying in the Logcat:Error getting documents: 
                                                                   com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestoreException: PERMISSION_DENIED: Missing or insufficient permissions.

Comment: In this case you need to go to your Firebase Console to add permissions. So go to `Firebase Console` -> `Authentication` -> `SIGN-IN METHOD` and enable `Email/Password`. Does it work now?

Comment: Don't also to change the rules is in my updated answer. Does it work?

Comment: Worked!!!.... Actually it was firestore rules. Those were set to `false`. Earlier I was working with Realtime Database so didn't notice. Thanks a tonn to you.